# Is there a way to obtain and store positions of matrix element in JAGS?

Tags: r, jags, winbugs, hierarchical-bayesian

I am developing a bayesian hierarchical model in R with BUGS code in JAGS.

In my model, I have two matrices that contain relevant information about each another in the same exact matrix position. My information is structured by rows. I apply a mathematical operation to the first matrix, Distmat, by row:

```
diffmat[i,j] <- abs(Distmat[birthterr[i],j] - Dist[i])
```

I am interested to record the column position of every minimum value in each row of diffmat in a new vector, to then apply this vector to the second matrix. This would be relatively easy in regular R code using functions "which" or "which.min":

```
a <- numeric()
for (i in 1:dim(diffmat)[1])
  for (j in 1:dim(diffmat)[2])
a[i] <- which.min(diffmat[i,])
```

And then apply vector "a" to the second matrix (terrmat) to obtain the values associated with Distmat positions:

```
b <- numeric(0)
for (i in 1:dim(diffmat)[1])
  for (j in 1:dim(diffmat)[2])
b[i] <- terrmat[i, a[i]]
```

However, apparently BUGS code does not recognize either which or which.min(), and I am struggling to find a way to store these matrix row positions in vectors. Perhaps there is a very simple solution to this, but I really got stuck there. Hope my info was enough clear.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal working example.  The analogs here are that `x` would be your `diffmat`.  I'm drawing it at random here, but it should still work if you're defining it otherwise.  Essentially, you rank the values of `x` in each row and make a new matrix `e` that is a dummy matrix that is coded 1 if `x[i,j]` is ranked 1 and 0 otherwise.  Then you take the inner product of that and a vector of values from `1:ncol(terrmat)` assuming `terrmat` and `diffmat` are of the same dimensions.  Then that gives you the column index of the first ranked value for observation `i`.  The `ymat` in the example below is where your `terrmat` would go.  I think it will be pretty slow on any real-sized problem, but it appears to work from the output below.

```
dl <- list(
ymat = matrix(1:3, ncol=3, nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
yinds = 1:3
)
mods <- "model{
  for(i in 1:5){
    for(j in 1:3){
      x[i,j] ~ dnorm(0,1)
      e[i,j] <- equals(rx[i,j], 1)
    }
    rx[i,1:3] <- rank(x[i,1:3])
    ind[i] <- inprod(e[i,], yinds)
    yval[i] <- ymat[i,ind[i]]
  }
  
}"

library(runjags)

out <- run.jags(mods, data=dl, monitor="yval")

out
# 
# JAGS model summary statistics from 20000 samples (chains = 2; adapt+burnin = 5000):
#   
#         Lower95 Median Upper95   Mean      SD Mode     MCerr MC%ofSD SSeff       AC.10    psrf
# yval[1]       1      2       3 1.9973  0.8139    2 0.0058421     0.7 19409  -0.0077146 0.99996
# yval[2]       1      2       3 2.0067 0.81605    3 0.0057704     0.7 20000  0.00049096  1.0003
# yval[3]       1      2       3 1.9895  0.8142    2 0.0057573     0.7 20000  0.00066309       1
# yval[4]       1      2       3 1.9973 0.81638    1 0.0057727     0.7 20000 -0.00040016 0.99998
# yval[5]       1      2       3  1.993 0.81611    1 0.0057708     0.7 20000  -0.0027988 0.99996
# 
# Total time taken: 0.7 seconds
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for this suggestion. With this code, my model now runs smoothly and converges properly. As you said, computational time increases quite a lot, but at the moment I cannot think of a more efficient alternative. Thanks again!